# How to rename the rows of a dataframe on the fly?

Tags: r, dataframe

I love to rename a vector on the fly with `setNames` (by on-the-fly I mean a function that returns the object):

```
my_vector <- c(1,2,3)
setNames(my_vector, c("a","b","c"))
# a b c
# 1 2 3
```

That works for dataframe column names as well

```
my_df <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow=3))
setNames(my_df, c("a","b","c"))
  a b c
1 1 4 7
2 2 5 8
3 3 6 9
```

Is there a way to do the same with the row names? I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
t(setNames(t(my_df), c("a","b","c")))
```

Comment: For future reference: for "what function do I need?" type queries, use `??` or `???` from the `sos` package.  For example `??"row names"`.

Comment: I think downvoters missed the whole point, here *"on the fly"* means that the function should return the modified object like `setNames` does, and unlike `rownames<-`.

Comment: @flodel, I'm one who has abstained from voting on the question or the answers. I'm still trying to understand how this feature would be used. `data.frame` has a `row.names` argument where row names can be added "on the fly" during creating the `data.frame`... and `dimnames`, `rownames` and `colnames` seem like quite reasonable approaches. Or is the point to not alter the original object?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I think there are two points. One is you want the function to return the object, so it can be used right away. I think that's what is meant by *on-the-fly*. `data.frame()` is for creating an object, not really modifying the attributes of an existing object (`my_df` is given). `dimnames`, `rownames` and `colnames` do modify attributes, but they do not return the object itself. The second point I made is not explicitly mentioned in the OP's question: since the OP wants something that behaves like `setNames`, he might want not to modify the original object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you can use `setattr` from the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
(setattr(my_df, "row.names", c("a", "b", "c")))

  X1 X2 X3
a  1  4  7
b  2  5  8
c  3  6  9
```

In fact, the object is modified in place (which is very helpful for large objects -- no copying the object).  You can use this for almost any attribute.

Note that `setattr` returns the object invisibly.

---

### Important Caveat:

Unlike `setNames`, the data.table functions `setnames` and `setattr` modify the object they are called on.  If you are planning to assign to a new object, you need to create a copy using `copy`:

If you unknowingly attempt `new_df <- setattr(my_df, "row.names", c("a", "b", "c"))`
**then both `new_df` and `my_df` will have *identical* values**

In this situation, you need to use `copy(my_df)`:
`new_df <- setattr(copy(my_df), "row.names", c("a", "b", "c"))`

However, if you're goal is to "re-assign" back to `my_df`, then you can save yourself a few keystrokes:

```
 ## instead of 
 my_df <- setattr(my_df, "row.names", c("a", "b", "c"))

 ## you can simply execute 
 setattr(my_df, "row.names", c("a", "b", "c"))
```

Comment: So this does modify `my_df`, unlike `setNames`.

Comment: @flodel, I edited the answer to make it abundantly clear that the function is modifying the object in place.  However, the ultimate result is the same as that of `rownames<-`

Answer (score 8):

I think what you mean by *on-the-fly* is you want the function to return the modified object. Since `rownames<-` does not do that for you, you will have to define your own function:

```
setRowNames <- function(df, row.names) {
   rownames(df) <- row.names
   df
}
```

You can have that function definition at the top of your script, or even hide it in your `Rprofile` or `Rprofile.site` (see `?Startup` if you are not familiar). Then inside your code, use `setRowNames(my_df, c("a", "b", "c"))`. It is concise, flexible, and reads nicely.

---

`t(setNames(t(my_df), c("a","b","c")))` does not work because transposing a data.frame gives you a matrix which does not have names but rownames and colnames.

Comment: I just looked inside `\`rownames<-\`` and saw that it returns the new data.frame. Maybe this has changed since your answer, but as of now `df<-data.frame(id=1:5);\`rownames<-\`(df,5:1)` does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
rownames(my_df) <- c("a","b","c")
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any builtin function that renames rows "on the fly".  However, a handy trick to get R to do anything "on the fly" is to combine multiple statements into a single one using curly brackets.  For example, if you have a dataframe `df` and you want to pass a copy of `df` with different row names to a function, you could do this:

```
fun({df0<-df;rownames(df0)<-foo;df0})
```

It is a little cumbersome, but it is still more concise than either defining and renaming `df0` on separate lines, or writing a special purpose function just to do this.

The downside of doing this is that `df0` remains defined after the function call, so if you do this a lot in the global environment, you might end up with a lot of spare objects.

On edit: I would encourage anyone interested in using the `{}` idiom for situations like this to read the comments on this answer.  @flodel and @RicardoSaporta are highly skilled R practitioners who have brought up some important points.  While I happen to disagree with them in this instance, I would recommend reading their comments (and my replies) to get an idea of the pros and cons of using the `{}` idiom.

Comment: I am trying to wrap my mind around your advice against writing a function. I highly disagree. You even admit your solution is cumbersome and creates unnecessary objects... You could wrap your `{...}` in a `local`, but seriously, you prefer that to a function?

Comment: I think it depends on how often you are going to do something like this.  It is certainly more concise than writing a function.  And writing function also creates an unnecessary object, if you're only going to use it once.  Also, if you use `{}` inside of a function, then the temporary object only gets stored locally and there is no namespace pollution.  In that case I would certainly favor `{}`.

Comment: Just to add.  If you are running an R session as opposed to a script, then in addition to polluting the namespace, defining a special purpose function also has the effect of polluting the command history, as does creating `df0` with a separate command.

Comment: Well, maybe it's a matter of taste or style.  I certainly understand your disagreement, and I imagine many people agree with you.  Personally, I've found the `{}` idiom to be extremely useful in many situations, in order to produce cleaner and more concise code.  A more typical example would be something like `{x<-foo();x-min(x)}` where I don't want to call `foo()` twice, and I also don't want to write a function `subtractMin` just for this (or even do a search to see if such a builtin function exists).  YMMV, but I think at least this is worth considering, hence my answer.

Comment: I have to say something about *"cleaner"* and *"concise"*. Between `{df0<-df;rownames(df0)<-foo;df0}` and `setRowNames(df, foo)`, which one is cleaner, which one is more concise, which one is more readable? Yes, I am overlooking the function creation; but assuming that something like this is going to be used more than once is not crazy, is it? We are talking about a general utility function. Finally, the argument about polluting the global environment or session history because I create one function is just ridiculous.

Comment: Well, you are assuming that `setRowNames` is the only quirky one-off function you are ever going to need.  That is not true.  There are a lot of things that R doesn't quite do in one function.  If you write a one-off function for every one, then your utility script or Rprofile will become unwieldy.  Obviously, if `setRowNames` already existed, I would go with that.  But given that it doesn't, I would rather use `{}` rather than define a whole new one-off function unless I know I am going to be needing this one operation many times.

Comment: @mrip, while there is a lot of utility in wrapping combined calls in braces (eg, setting seeds), I fully agree with flodel here. Creating the function, imho, is not only a lot cleaner and reusable, but it also makes the code so much more easy to follow when you are looking over it again 5 months from now.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Fair enough.  I think reasonable people can disagree about this.  Personally, I would rather go back five months and find four less lines of code and no one-off function.  For example, suppose that you had a script that required 10 different such one off functions.  Would you rather read 10 lines of code with `{}` or fifty lines of code, forty of which are functions that are used only once.  Then again, I use `{}` a lot, so for me it's not difficult to follow at all.  Like I said, I think it's a matter of style, but I welcome the critique and discussion.

Comment: personally, I use  reallyLongAndDescriptive function names, so that I know exactly what they are doing.  I keep my functions in a personal utils file and a good text editor (sublime text 3) so that when I need to find a function, I hit CMD+R and type a few letters and I am right at it.  I move very fast

Comment: I also have a util file, though I favor short function names -- a choice at odds with the current "mainstream", I know.  I use emacs/ess which does a fine job of completion.  However, as my utils file grew and grew over time, and I cleaned it out periodically, I became more selective in what I allow in there.  `setRowNames` would certainly not make the cut, in part since I am so used to `{}` that I would almost just use it reflexively if I ever needed it (which I don't think I ever will).  Much more common are things like `{x<-foo();x-min(x)}` or `x[{i<-bar();i | is.na(i)},]` etc.